# React Route is not working in Laravel React Scaffold project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React routes like this in my Laravel React project.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardPage}/>
    <Route exact path="/variations" component={AddVariationTypePage} /> 
</Switch>
```

It was working fine in localhost. After uploading the project to the live server route doesn't work.
when I remove "**exact**" keyword from the route it shows the page but does not change the page because it's obvious without **exact** keyword it does not change. but the main problem comes when I use "**exact**" keyword on the router like the above example, its shows nothing on the server. the page went blank. I think it's the problem for "**exact**" keyword. So can anyone please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Make sure you provide `exact` prop to only the `root path` that is `/`

Comment: Thanks mate. Solved it. Routes weren't working as I didn't create a subdomain for the app.